# Realization of BFS in relational databases

Tags: java, mysql, sql, nosql

I need to use a structure of ternary tree which has to be stored somewhere (I chose relational DB, but I still can change it).

My DB tree looks like:

[image: Tree example]

For example my relation contains columns - `Id`, `child1Id`, `child2Id`, `child3Id` and `is_active`

The problem is that I have to provide ability of BFS by boolean parameter. For example on the picture Node#35 should be found.
Of course I know how to realize BFS with ready data in java, but to do it i need to receive whole the tree from DB. 
Is it possible to do it through an SQL query? 
Or maybe anyone can suggest any better solution than to store it on relational DB?

Comment: if your data has graph/tree structure and most of your queries will be related to graphs then you should use some graph db like neo4j. All graph traversal algos will be available out of the box.

Comment: Thank you! I guess thats the best way to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is using graph DB instead of relational DB, as it was suggested in comments.
But if it is possible to use only relational DB, one of the ways is to add additional fields to table with nodes - `depth` and `position_in_layer`.. 
`depth = parent.depth+1`, `positionInLayer = (parent.positionInLayer - 1) * 3 + childNum`, where 3 for ternary tree (for binary it would be 2), childnum - which of the childs current node is.
For instance, when we add 2nd child to node 5 in 5th layer it will have depth 6 and position 4*3+2 = 14. It will be 14th element in 6th layer.
With such fields binary search could be realized layer by layer with queries like
`select * from node where depth=i and is_active=0 order by position_in_layer asc limit 1` where i - layer number (from 1 to `SELECT MAX(depth) FROM node`).
There was not bad result - searching the last element by BFS in tree with ~9800 nodes was done just for 22 ms (with added index)